# How do I interpret multidimensional vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, vector

I don't understand the syntax of a multidimensional vector.

Multidimensional arrays are pretty straight forward.

```
foo[3][5];
```

That's 5 elements with 3 elements each.

Vectors are not so much straight forward.

```
vector<vector<int>> foo(n);
```

I read this as for every foo, the "type" is vector. How does using a vector for another vector's type make it bidimensional? And also, is `vector<int>` still the same as a vector with an identifier, a vector with empty ints?

Comment: Maybe if you write `vector<vector<int>> foo(3, vector<int> (5));` will make it a little bit clear?

Comment: I understand what it mean and how it works. I just don't understand why `vector<int>` is used as an int. Is it safe to say that `vector<int>` means a vector of ints and `vector<vector<int>>` means a vector of a vector of ints?

Comment: @JimGordon Yes, that's what it means. (But where do you see a vector being "used as an int"?)

Comment: @molbdnilo `vector<vector<int>>`. The `vector<int> is where the other vector's `int` would be.

Comment: The bit between `<` and `>` is the type of the elements. `vector<int>` is a type like other types, and most types can be stored in a vector, including vectors. (Arrays is a notable exception.)

Comment: I think it makes sense now. A vector of ints for each int from the other vector.
@molbdnilo

Answer (score 2):

You've got the understanding of `int foo[3][5];` correct: it's an outer array of three inner arrays, each one of which contains 5 ints.

Oversimplfying a little for the sake of this discussion, but if you consider arrays and vectors as interchangeable `vector<vector<int>> foo;` isn't really any different.

It's an outer vector, each member of which is an inner vector containing ints.

So thinking in terms of matrices, outer array/vector is the column, inner array/vector is the row.  It's really not that different.    And that row / column nature is what makes it two dimensional.

No arguments that under the hood the implementations are extremely different, but when you're using them, they will behave very similar to one another.

Answer (score 0):

`foo` isn't really a "multidimensional" array, it's an array whose elements are also arrays.

With

```
int foo[3][5];
```

`foo` is an array with three elements, each of which is an array with five elements.
That is, `foo[1]` is an array of five `ints` (its type is `int[5]`).

A vector of vectors works like an array of arrays, except their sizes are not fixed.

```
vector<vector<int>> foo(n);
```

creates a vector with `n` elements, each of which is an empty vector (because vectors are empty by default).

```
vector<vector<int>> bar(3, vector<int>(5));
```

would create a vector with three `vector<int>` elements, and `bar[1]` would be a vector with five `int` elements.